# Performing Boolean Transformations in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, 3d-engine

I am currently trying to develop a small simulation program in xna that takes a model and breaks it up into several smaller pieces.

The only way I was thinking would be to take the original object, copy it, then remove a chunk from one (using a pre-built model) using subtraction boolean, then perform an intersect boolean operation on the other, and presto, two objects which together look like the original, but can be separated individually.

The only issue is, I have no idea how to do it, or if it is even possible.

I would prefer to use XNA, but I'd be open to using any other free/open source 3d engine if anyone knows how. Preferably something with a nice simple .net wrapper, but probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robust boolean operations on solids are outside of the scope of a graphics engine like XNA.
One I've used before is [open cascade](http://www.opencascade.org/)
A lot depends on the complexity of your models. Maybe opencascade is overkill for what you are trying to accomplish. It is intended for CAD environments.

I found this old sourceforge project, which might help:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/djxcbo/

Comment: yeah, I thought xna might be a bit simple, but the idea I had was to write a class that could do it, as close to real time as possible, for porting a program with it in to xbox if it gets used

Comment: btw, djxcbo looks quite good, im gonna have a look through it